# Fatal error: Class 'CassandraClient' not found in /home/dev001/projects/Thrift/gen-php/cassandraTest.php

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift

I have installed cassandra and apache Thrift. I have created a PHP test page to test it.When I am running it returning the following error.

Fatal error: Class 'CassandraClient' not found in /home/dev001/projects/Thrift/gen-php/cassandraTest.php on line 15

When I checked cassandra through the cassandra-cli, Its showing the following error.

```
power@power-desktop:/home/dev001$ cassandra-cli
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:255)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at  java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
... 3 more
Exception connecting to 127.0.0.1/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.1.0~rc1

Type 'help;' or '?' for help.
Type 'quit;' or 'exit;' to quit.

[default@unknown]
```

Please tell me why this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you don't have cassandra listening on the correct IP/port.  Run a `netstat -an` to see if it is listening on port 9160.

Having said that:

- [Cassandra not working with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164034/cassandra-not-working-with-php/10166284#10166284)
- [Cassandra with PHP - on call of cassandra-test.php I get "Call to undefined method CassandraClient::batch_insert()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256332/cassandra-with-php-on-call-of-cassandra-test-php-i-get-call-to-undefined-meth)

In summary, the consensus among the masses is that you should avoid using raw thrift wherever possible and use one of the maintained client libraries:  [Which PHP client library to use with Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401282/which-php-client-library-to-use-with-cassandra)

Comment: What steps did you take to debug?  At the minimum, does `nestat -an` show anything listening on port 9160?

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal type:

`# service cassandra start`

before using cassandra.

This starts the cassandra deamon. which must be running before sending commands to cassandra

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error
but when i started cassandra via cassandra_installation_dir/bin/cassandra and then  "cassandra_installation_dir/bin/cassandra-cli --host 192.168.1.90" i was able to log in.
Try this way if that works.